# useHistory react-router-dom invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` and it doesn't seem to work. Throws invalid hook call

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
<...>
import { Signup } from './Signup.js';
import { Login } from './Login.js';
import { Account } from './Account.js';
import { AuthProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    <...>

    render() {
        return(
            <>
               <...>
                <Router>
                    <AuthProvider>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
                            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
                        </Switch>
                    </AuthProvider>
                </Router>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Account.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Account = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    return(
        <h1>Hello...</h1>
    );
}
```

And it throws error on this line: `const history = useHistory();`

**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:**
<...>

Latest React version, latest React Router version, also if it makes any difference I installed `react-router-dom` after `create-react-app`. Link(s) and routes itself are working without any issues. Found few topics on this here but no clear/working solution. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the supplied code snippets. Think you try reproducing this into a *running* codesandbox and provide the link in your question so we may live debug in it?

Comment: Similar issue, no idea why it wasn't working. I ended up deleting node_modules, cleared the cache and reinstalled the dependencies. Worked perfectly fine after that.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution: previously I installed react-router-dom directly from macOS terminal and everything worked except for useHistory, however this time I installed react-router-dom directly from VS code's terminal and it seems to be working fine now. Hope this helps to anybody having this issue.

Comment: wow after 4 hours work and search 
your simple solution  work with me 
me to ( i have clone repo  and run yarn after that useHistory not working ) 
but after install manually ( yarn add react-router-dom ) every think  work fine 

THX PRO 

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was caused by something I couldn't find elsewhere.

Taking your example, I was using something of the likes:

```
<Route path="/signup" children={Signup} />
// So I changed it to
<Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
```

Notice `component` prop in `<Route />`

I believe the Error was caused because component just calls the component and children appends it so I would be calling react and/or hooks twice.

If anyone knows and can explain better, feel free to do so!

Comment: I want to add that I had this same issue when using useParams(). I was able to solve it with the above modification.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the package.json and noticed that I hadn't `npm install react-router-dom`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29779100)